# Android JNI native library not packaged to apk

Tags: android, java-native-interface

While transforming my project from eclipse to AS.
I got a fatal error which caused by "the lib not found " problem.

My project contains jni codes,compiled by ndk build system and managed by the "Android.mk" file.

After transformed I found that two of the libraries(.so) was *not* packaged into the apk file while other libraries are packaged correctly.

Here is part of the content of "Android.mk" file,all libraries are packaged but "curl" and "jsqlite".The two files do exist in the right path.Is there any suggestion,thks!!

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
MY_LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := skia
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libskia.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := iconv
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libiconv.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS :=
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := jsqlite
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libjsqlite.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := -lz
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := curl
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libcurl.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS :=
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := gdal
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libgdal.so
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := jsqlite
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := -lz
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Have you tried JniLib folder?

Comment: Is it a runtime error or a build error?